# How can I get a change history of faunaDB document?

Tags: faunadb

FaunaDB's At() function looks so nice! I wonder if I can log a time series of sensor data into one document, and draw a time series chart by At() function and **change history** of the document.

So, is there any way to get a change history of FaunaDB's documents? Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Events($ref)` will give you the history of a document. The amount of retained history is configurable. The complete docs for `Event` is found [here](https://docs.fauna.com/fauna/current/api/fql/functions/events).

That said I'm not sure I'd choose to implement a sensor time series that way. I'd be more inclined to write a separate document per reading. Mostly because it's easier to work with first class values for time series and if you need to record quickly you won't run into conflicts.

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, function Events($ref) works perfectly!
Also thank you for your kindly suggestion, so typical usage of history might be a rollback of data?

Comment: Rollback is definitely a strong usecase, audit is another. Lots of reasons to browse history. A top level bank balance might be a fun one to look at the history of, but I'd still store the transactions separately.